# tableau divide one measure by another

Tags: multiple-columns, tableau-api, divide

I have data like below in Tableau.

```
school  student marks
a       xy      5
a       xy      10
a       ab      15
b       cd      20
b       cd      25
a       cd      30
```

I want to find total marks, count of marks and average marks by student and school

in case of the below two tables i was able to create first 3columns, how could i create the 4th column? 2nd and third columns are measures.
Is it possible to perform a row level calculation?

```
student sum of marks    count of marks  average marks
xy      15              2               7.5
ab      15              1               15
cd      75              3               25

school  sum of marks    count of marks  average marks
a       60              4               15
b       55              2               27.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a calculated field as "average marks":

```
SUM(marks)/COUNT(marks)
```

Or simply select average of that measure, instead Sum or Count (right click, Measure: Average)

Comment: Are the both ways same in terms of speed and accuracy and efficieny?

Comment: @Ni_Tempe I think that both ways are the same in terms of speed and accuracy, but the second should be more efficient because avoid creating a measure.

Comment: please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216184/tableau-create-a-button-to-go-to-a-another-sheet-or-dashboard-within-same-file if possible